# vs-code giving typescript help in plain node project

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code

I have a verry simple nodeJs project; my pacakge.json is just

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "node-static": "^0.7.11"
  }
}
```

I've manually copied in the d3.js file and am serving it as a static file - so not transpiling or anything going on.

Vs-code is STILL giving me some typescript help - which is AWESOME. But it stopped working for a few minutes; which make me realize I have no idea how its giving me the docs.

Does vs-code have some default ways of linking typescript definitions?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Typescript (then VSCode) has four ways to link typings definitions to your code:

1) It looks for `node_modules/@types/yourpackage` (also global, I suppose)

2) It looks for `.d.ts` files in the packages you are importing

3) It uses the types you tells it to use through `/// <reference path="" />` at the top of your file (but I think this might be deprecated, but I'm not really sure)

4) It uses the `types` key in your package.json and scans the directories you specify in its array to look for `.d.ts` with the same name of your imports

E.g.

```
import * as shaka from "shaka-player"
```

It will look for `shaka.d.ts` (but it has to declare a module named `shaka-player` in it).

Hope this answers to your question!

Comment: Thanks for those pointers; as far as I can tell I haven't got any of those options setup. So seems like vs-code is doing one of them somewhat automagically. I'll see if I can track down what.

Comment: Note to self - the ts definitions are coming from /home/ishweretheheartis/.cache/typescript/3.8/node_modules/@types/d3-selection/index.d.ts

Comment: I think that Typescript might be using that package too (but I'm not sure) and therefore it includes the typings it has. I actually don't why they are there and why it finds them there. Maybe there's a fifth way it uses to find the typings.